# Having issue parsing yaml file (JS-YAML - NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, parsing

I am looking to parse following yml file (fake.yml)

```
:currency: 'USD'
:Markets:  [
    {
    :id: ABC-001,
    :name: ASIA001,
    :fruits: [
      {
        :name: Apple,
        :id: 123
      },
      {
        :name: Orange,
        :id: 124
      },
      {
        :name: mango,
        :id: 125
      }
    ]
    },
    {
    :id: EUR-001,
    :name: EUR001,
    :fruits: [
      {
        :name: Apple,
        :id: 333
      },
      {
        :name: Orange,
        :id: 334
      },
      {
        :name: mango,
        :id: 336
      }
    ]
    }
]
```

I have tried simple safeLoad() function but not sure how to access id/name for all fruits for each market:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const yaml = require('js-yaml');

try {
    let fileContents = fs.readFileSync('c:/temp/fake.yml');
    let dataArray = yaml.safeLoad(fileContents);
    console.log(dataArray);

    console.log("******-" + dataArray.Markets); // Not sure how to handle :Markets 
 } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Here is the output when I run above code snippet:

{
      ':dl_dir': 'C:\Temp',
      ':Markets': [
        { ':id': 'ABC-001', ':name': 'ASIA001', ':fruits': [Array] },
        { ':id': 'EUR-001', ':name': 'EUR001', ':fruits': [Array] }
      ]
    }
    ******-undefined

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: That's not a correct yaml structure

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately this yaml comes from a third party system and cannot change it.  II need to update ID/Name fields...maybe I will try  to process it as text file and see if it works if not a valid.

Comment: I just ran the yml file thru online validators and it says the format is valid.

Comment: Validator is lying. I'd suggest to read about yaml syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the response again.  Here is what worked for me.  I had to use dataArray[':Markets'][':id'] to get the value ABC-001...simple for/forEach loop gave me the values for each fruit.

Comment: You can write an answer and select it as accepted if it works

Answer (score 0):

```
 dataArray[':Markets'][':id'] ==>
```

gives 'ABC-001' as expected. This appears to be just syntax issue on my part.